# How to setup DNSSEC for DNS records on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, nameservers, dnssec

Model:

I have my domain registered in provider subreg.cz and he have ability of DNSSEC.
I am pointing domain to AWS Route 53 with AWS nameservers.
Trying setup DNSSEC on DNS records.
Without any success.

Why I am doing it?

I have for domain ALIAS on AWS Cloudfront with offered certificate.

I want enable DNSSEC for this ALIAS and don't know what is the best way without loosinng possibility of Certificate.

Can you please, share your suggestions, how I can achieve solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, Amazon AWS' Route 53 service does not, currently, support your workflow.

> Route 53 supports DNSSEC for domain registration but *does not support
>   DNSSEC for DNS service*.([from AWS Route 53 Support docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-configure-dnssec.html))

Answer (score 2):

`DNSSEC` is [now supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-configuring-dnssec.html) by AWS Route 53 for both `DNSSEC signing` (Hosting service) and `domain registration` (Registrar service).

Answer (score 0):

> (click) your hostedzone -> DNSSEC signing tab -> Enable DNSSEC signing

[image]